# Correct configuration for cli-config.php for Doctrine ORM 2.1 without a framework

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

i have this configuration for cli-config.php  Doctrine CLI 2.2.0-DEV

```
<?php
require_once '../lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\ORM', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\DBAL', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/doctrine-dbal/lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor/doctrine-common/lib'));
$classLoader->register();
$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Symfony', realpath(__DIR__ . '/../lib/vendor'));
$classLoader->register();
$classloader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('MyProject', __DIR__ );
$classloader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);
//$driverImpl = $config->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(array(__DIR__."/mapping"));
$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(realpath(__DIR__.'/mapping/yml/'));
//$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(realpath(__DIR__.'/mapping/xml/'));

$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);

$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
    'path'     => '192.168.10.210',
    'dbname'   => 'my_database_name',
    'user'     => 'root',
    'password' => 'my_password'
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

$helpers = array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
);
```

i can generate YML files, XML files and Annotation hten i can get the Entitites but i can get proxies.